# read_excel() function auto convert int to float

Tags: python, pandas

when I am reading the file using *read_excel()* function integer columns are auto-converted into the float datatype in pandas python when any *NAN* value present.
like in below example:

```
A B C D
1 2 s 3.9
        
3 4 d 2.0

when I am reading the file using read_excel().

Dataframe is like this
A   B   C  D
1.0 2.0 s 3.9
Nan Nan Nan nan
3.0 4.0 d  2.0
```

can anyone suggest me how to stop this auto conversion from int to float while reading the file in pandas

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your problem, you should mark it as resolved by clicking the tick mark ( _or upvote_ ). [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `dtype=object` to avoid that.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
df
     A    B    C    D
0  1.0  2.0    s  3.9
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  4.0    d  2.0
df=pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', dtype=object)
df
     A    B    C    D
0    1    2    s  3.9
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2    3    4    d  2.0
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
df=pd.read_excel("path to your file",na_filter=False)
```

output:

```
df
Out[71]: 
          A  B  C    D
0         1  2  s  3.9
1                     
2         3  4  d    2
```

Comment: can you please give one example if possible.