# Pandas read_excel reads integers as floats ending with decimals .999 or .001

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Instead of integers I'm getting floats that end with decimals .999 or .001.

I'm trying to read an Excel .xlsx file containing product data into a Pandas Dataframe with `read_excel`. Normally the EAN (UPC) codes work like they should, but now for some reason they show up as a float instead of integers.

I've checked the file with Excel and Numbers, all the EANs there are integers and using `Increase Decimal` shows .000 for every single one.

If I specify `dtype` as `int` for the `read_excel`, it cuts the decimals and everything with .001 shows correctly, but the ones with .999 don't. If I don't use `dtype` it shows the column as `float64`

`round` seems to work, but I wouldn't want to use it, as this problem shouldn't exist in the first place.

For example:

| index | EAN | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18492 | 615357122276.9999 | Taylors Pure Assam musta tee 20ps |
| 18493 | 615357122252.9999 | Taylors hauduke 20pss lemon ginger |
| 18494 | 615357119764.9999 | Taylors green jasmine leaf tea 125g |
| 18495 | 615357119703.0001 | Taylors musta irtotee 125g English Break |

Comment: Using `dtype={'EAN': object}` I get the following as `head()` of the dataframe
EAN
8713913006350.000977
2875172000008
8712785002329.999023
8717662025686.000977
6430067777180
6430067777869
6430048441369
6430048446135
6430048441055
6430048441153.999023

Comment: Have you tried setting the dtype to integer?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591466/python-pandas-how-to-specify-data-types-when-reading-an-excel-file

Comment: Yes, setting it as integer just cuts the decimals, so if for example 615357119764.9999 is shown as 615357119764 when it should be 615357119765. 

`round` seems to give the right numbers, but it still doesn't explain why it shows up like that in the first place. This has never happened before.

Comment: Null and NaN values in your xlsx file in the EAN column may force it to turn into float values when read with pandas. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65528499/18505884 This answer may help if you have Null values
I'd say if it was working before, it's likely something minor changed and now it won't work. Think back and examine any small changes made to your files.